# Microsoft UI Automation for Customize word addin

Tags: add-in, ui-automation, words

I tried out UI Automation for WPF testing and it works very well for us. Now I want to use UI Automation test for our custom microsoft word addin (which includes a ribbon tab and other controls) but I am unable to find information regarding to how to do it in UI Automation (For example how to click on the custom addin tab on the ribbon). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Think of using one of the following if available

1. Codded UI test - visual studio 2010 has it
2. Microsoft Test Manager has action recording and you can use that.
3. figure out the shortcut keys for your add in and you may use http://www.autoitscript.com/site/